# Keep reactive helper from updating a meteor template

Tags: meteor

I'm looking at how to turn off reactivity within a template helper function.  I only want the data rendered when the template is initially populated and not when the underlying data changes.

My current helper has two reactive variables:  one is a Session.get() and the other is a *Collection*.findOne().  I've tried to wrap the Session.get() in a Tracker.nonreactive() call and set the reactive option to false on the *Collection*.findOne() but I'm still seeing the reactive behavior.

```
Template.characterSkills.helpers({
  data : function () {
    var characterID = Tracker.nonreactive(function () {
      return Session.get("currentCharacterID");
    });

    if(characterID) {
      var record = Characters.findOne(
        { _id : characterID },
        { 
          reactive : false,
          fields : { skills : 1 } 
        }
      );

      if(record && record.skills)
        return record.skills;
    }
  }
});
```

I've been trying to work this issue for about half a day now.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the name `data` for your helper which is reserved. So if you have another helper or an iron router route with `data` in it, or this template is a subtemplate of another template its likely to redraw too.

Try renaming it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure to find and set the record when the template is rendered and then return a static object in the template helper:

```
Template.characterSkills.helpers({
  dataItem: function(){
    return record.get();
  }
});

Template.characterSkills.onCreated(function(){
  record.set(Session.get("currentCharacterID"));
});

var record = function(){
  var local = {};
  return {
    set: function(characterId){
      if ( characterID) local = Characters.findOne({_id: characterID},{fields : { skills : 1 }});
      else local = null;
    },
    get: function(){
      return local;
    }
 }();
```

Although even this feels like too much work. Surely there's an easier way.

Comment: I agree.  It's not the "Meteor way" answer I was looking for.  You'd think it would be easier to turn off reactivity.

Comment: Thanks, but still no dice.  The way Meteor encapsulates js files seems to be interfering with the closure.  It doesn't like it at all...and I've tried several different ways of doing it.  I think I'm going to bypass the helper and populate the table directly with jQuery in a onRendered callback.

Comment: I ran a similar setup in a sample app. The closure works fine but I should have called `record.set()` in the `onCreated` handler and not the onRendered one. It ends up working non reactively.